# Align on same line the button and badge on the bootstrap panel header

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can I get the button and the bootstrap badge on the same row within the bootstrap panel? I also need the text 'Selected Rows' and the badge to be pulled right on the panel.

Plunker code as below
https://plnkr.co/edit/QNLe7n?p=preview**

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div>
            <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" dx-button="addButton"></span>
            <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" class="pull-right">
                  <h3>Selected Records: </h3>
                    <span class ="badge badge-default">{{selectedRowCount}}</span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. Refer For more details [Bootstrap Grid System](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/). [Updated Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4DXIz7HlYgWVTQ29uhuo?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("myApp", ["dx"]);
(function() {
    'use strict';


    angular
      .module('myApp')
      .controller('PendingRequestsController', PendingRequestsController);
      
    PendingRequestsController.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function PendingRequestsController($scope) {
 
      $scope.addButton = {
        text: "Add Button",
        icon: "plus",
        type: "success",
        onClick: function(e) {}
      };
      
      $scope.selectedRowCount = 14;

    }

}());
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*"  src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.11/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/globalize/0.1.1/globalize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.4/js/dx.all.js"></script>
   <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.4/css/dx.common.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/16.2.4/css/dx.light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="myapp.module.js"></script>
  <script src="pending.controller.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="PendingRequestsController" >
    
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" dx-button="addButton"></span>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-xs-6 text-right">
                <h4 style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;">
                      Selected Records:<span class ="badge badge-default">{{selectedRowCount}}</span>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]
 Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks Manish, this does work to a large extent but the issue I see is that they are not centred within the panel. How can I vertical align them to the middle of the panel

Comment: middle of he panel? didnt get you. If you want them to be aligned in the middle of the panel. Then why are ypu keeping them in panel heading. keep them in panel body. inside panel heading they are vertically aligned to center. If you can just shoe a drawing of layout you want to achieve. i can help you better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Manish. Middle as in vertically centred .. so within the panel header I want the heading and the button to be vertically aligned in the centre. The button has to be pulled to the right though. Hope this makes it clear what I am looking to do .

Comment: I think i m not gettig the exact requirement.Correct me if i'm wrong `PanelHeader=> Two columns Left(With button pulled to right) Right(With text pulled to right)` and the header contents to be vertically center aligned. Panel body will have some content. Have attached an image please let know if that is what you need? Also this is the structure that bootstrap panel follows

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes in the HTML. Please check. Here is the updated plunker [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/QNLe7n?p=preview)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <span dx-button="addButton"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <span class="pull-right">
                      <h3 class="pull-left" style="margin:0">Selected Records: </h3>
                      <span class="badge badge-default ng-binding" style="">14</span>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Please check and let me know if I was able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h3 {
  display: inline;
}
.panel {
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div>
      <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" dx-button="addButton"></span>
      <span style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;" class="pull-right">
                  <h3>Selected Records: </h3>
                    <span class ="badge badge-default">{{selectedRowCount}}</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you want to achieve this.